# Why am I getting TypeError: create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username' in AbstractUser?

Tags: django

I have written a custom User model, and when trying to create a superuser got the following error:

```
TypeError: create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'
```

When I run the command for creating a superuser, Django didn't asked me to enter the username field.

**Model Class:**

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=250, null=False, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

**Updated:**

When I changed USERNAME_FIELD to *username* from *email*, it didn't ask me to enter email, and I got the following error:

```
TypeError: create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'email'
```

It was all that I have written, and I am new to Django unable to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Can you explain what do you want to archive and show how did you exactly call 'create_superuser()'?

If you call it from python code then you should probably provide username 'manually':

```
CustomUser.objects.create_superuser(username="some_username")
```

**Update**:

I think that your problem is described in following issue:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26412

To solve your problem you have to set `null=True` in `username` field and overwrite the default UserManager in your model:

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=250, null=False, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

CustomUserManager implementation:

```
from django.apps import apps
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, UserManager
from django.db import models

class CustomUserManager(UserManager):
    def create_user(self, username=None, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return super(CustomUserManager, self).create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, username=None, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return super(CustomUserManager, self).create_superuser(username, email, password, **extra_fields)

    def _create_user(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        GlobalUserModel = apps.get_model(self.model._meta.app_label, self.model._meta.object_name)
        username = GlobalUserModel.normalize_username(username)
        user = self.model(username=username, email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.password = make_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

Check if it works for you and if so then pls mark my answer as useful.

Comment: python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py createsuperuser
This is how ...i tried to create superuser

Comment: Do you have AUTH_USER_MODEL = "your_app.CustomUser" set in your settings.py?

Comment: Pls check my "Update".

Comment: yes i have added AUTH_USER_MODEL, and have create superuser using following command:-
python manage.py createsuperuser

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add 'username' to REQUIRED_FIELDS

```
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username',]
```

so It will prompt in your terminal to add username while creating superuser successfully.

OR,

you may give value for username in CustomUser model as None
(in case you didn't need the username field in your CustomUser table)

```
username = None
```

So that Django will delete the column from the database when you run migrations

Good Luck